# Text has space to the right

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="brm-item-name">204 Banane, Milch &amp; Erdbeeren                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="pop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button></div>
```

`"204 Banane, Milch &amp; Erdbeeren             "` is pulling from database but text does not have a space in the database. The space here is giving me trouble when writing css. Do you have any suggestions on this?

[image: Photo]

Comment: We can't possibly know the root cause of this looking at the code you have given. How are you pulling it from the database? A hacky workaround would be to remove multiple spaces from that text using Javascript.

Comment: Is it possible to remove this space in css?

Comment: It depends on how you're injecting it, but html should be *whitespace agnostic* so shouldn't matter on the frontend

Comment: Two things come to mind.
1. Use **trim()** for the field you retrieve from the database, just to ensure any spaces are being removed.
2. Make sure in your code no spaces are between the closing PHP tag and the button tag. Like so: **?><button>**

Comment: Your text between example and image are different. And one has quotes, the other does not.  I think your data has tabs at the end.  I think it makes no difference to rendering.  You are worried about the source, which has spaces because you put them in.  Just put <button> on the next line and see if it makes you happier.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it using jQuery trim().

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.brm-item-name').trim();


})
```